# How to toggle CKEditor with normal textarea in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I am working on a Rails project. I am able to display the CKEditors in text-areas using:

```
<% 1.upto(4) do |i| %>
  <%= cktext_area_tag "fields_name#{i}" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to toggle all the CKEditor text-areas to normal text-areas on clicking a link:

```
<%=link_to "Show as editor","#",:id=>"showEditor"%>
```

How is it possible?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: get the instance and call destroy

Comment: @epascarello : could you please explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEDITOR is a global object and it has a property `instances` that is an object representing all of the editors on the page

Following loops over the instances and updates the textarea value, then destroys the editor instance

```
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
     var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[instance];
     editor.updateElement();
     editor.destroy();
     editor = null;
}
```

Example for single instance http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/ajax.html

Comment: Thanks! It works. But the toggle is not working. The CKEditors are not enabled on clicking the "Show as editor" link again.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to just put them in `view source` mode? To activate again you will need to reintialize them with your original config object

Comment: No. we got a requirement like this. Is it possible to display the normal text-areas first and on clicking on the link "Show as editor" CKEditors will be shown?

Comment: so use the manual initialization as per the docs. You probably have them being set by class now which auto initializes them. follow example I linked to. You just stated in question you wanted them to go to textarea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68465/discussion-between-rahulv-and-charlietfl).